# Getting data from another view controller (not via passing the data forward or backward) in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Say I have View Controller A, where I have an array with data.
Now I also have a couple of other View Controllers (B,C,D, etc...)where I need that array.

I know I could pass the data forward using segues to each of the other View Controllers. But It seems not the perfect solution for me as I have to pass the data each time through a lot of different View Controllers

I would rather have a method where I define in View controller B "Get the data from View Controller A"

(As I understand passing data backwards is not what I want to achieve because I don't want to change the array in View controller B and pass it back to View Controller A. I only want to read/get the data within View Controller B  from View Controller A.

Can somebody point me to a solution for this? Or do I have to pass the data forward from VC A to VC B?

I guess it is a matter of taste but I would rather write my code in VC B/C/D in case I need the data from VC A than passing each time data from A to every other VC...

Comment: why don't you use a singleton to hold the data instead of holding it in ViewController A?

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't knew about "singletons", I will research that!

Comment: Yup the answer below is the way to do it. If you need any other help let us know. It basically allows you to persist data across the entire app

Comment: Thanks again, could you look into my comment in the answer below?

Comment: While you're researching singletons, I suggest you take a look at this: https://cocoacasts.com/are-singletons-bad/ There are cases when singletons can be an appropriate choice but the problem you're trying to solve doesn't appear to be one of them. This topic is a holy war and I'm not trying to start up a big debate here. Just trying to help you learn early on what kind of choice you make if you take the easy way.

Comment: It sounds you need an actual Model layer. Read up on MVC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a singleton class. let's say DataManager.

```
class DataManager: NSObject {

  // A Singleton instance
  static let shared = DataManager()

  // your array
  var dataArray = [String]()
}
```

now access this array from anywhere in the app.

```
Print(DataManager.shared.dataArray)
```

Comment: Hmmm... I already created my Array in my "View Controller Class" quite complicated, how can I pass this final array into my DataManger Class, so that it gets global?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? If you can post some code about the array that you are using (the type etc.) that would be helpful. If you are using the above class then you should do it like this DataManager.shared.dataArray = yourCurrentArray

Comment: Thank you, I got it and it works! But I think I need a break for today :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to pass the data forward from VC A to VC B?

You don't **have** to, but you **should**.

The suggested singleton pattern is considered an anti-pattern nowadays, you can read more about why here: [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

It's not just a matter of taste, your code will be more maintainable if you avoid singletons.

Even if you use CoreData instead of an array in ViewController A, you will/should pass references from A to B, be it the `Managed Object Context` or an array of objects that you retrieved from CoreData in ViewController A. You can see this happening in the default template provided by XCode/Apple for a MasterDetail app with CoreData (just create a new project for that).